# Django: Automatic assignment of primary key in MySql failing

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am following the [Effective Django](http://www.effectivedjango.com/latex/EffectiveDjango.pdf) tutorial with the change of using MySql instead of sqlite3.
Following the [official recommendation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/) of Django and given that I am working with Python3.4 I am using [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) driver.
I have created the following model as indicated in the tutorial:

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    fName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    lName = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    eMail = models.EmailField()

    def str(self):
        return ' '.join([self.fName, self.lName])
```

db has sync'ed (migrated) ok.Nonetheless, when creating through the shell a contact

```
a = Contact('John', 'Doe')
```

and then saving it

```
a.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'John'
```

which does not appear when I provide an explicit integer (taken as primary key???) as first argument

```
a = Contact(1, 'John', 'Doe')
```

Why isn't automatic pk assignment working as it should?

I am using Django 1.7.7 / Python 3.4 on virtualenv
Here are the settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'addressbook',
        'USER': 'abuser',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
}
```

}

abuser has been granted all privileges with grant option on the addressbook (as also on the test_addressbook) db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a model instance you should use keyword arguments instead of positional:

```
a = Contact(fName='John', lName='Doe')
a.save()
```